# Problems with underextrusion

Tags: troubleshooting, underextrusion, hbot-3d-1.1

I have a problem with, what I think is underextrusion (see attached photos), but I'd like to ask you If my assumption is correct. If it is underextrusion could you advice me which slicer settings should I adjust?

The nozzle isn't blocked, so now I'm trying to solve the matter by increasing flow rate, but apart from that and e-step calibration I have no idea.

[image]

I have an HBot 3D 1.1 printer (it's a CoreXY style printer)  which I use together with Cura. I print in PLA at  200 °C. The print bed is set to 70 °C. I use a print cooling fan at 100 %. The layer height I set to 0.2 mm, the line width is set to 0.4 mm from the 0.4 mm nozzle. The Printing Speed is set to 30 mm/s for walls and 60 mm/s for infill. My retraction is 6.5 mm off at  25 mm/s.

Two other settings I've adjusted are print jerk (from 20 to 1 mm/s) and acceleration (from 3000 mm/s² to 500 mm/s²).I've changed them to stop the printer from shaking too much.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've messed a little with settings. Turns out that turning z-hop completely fixed the issue.

Comment: It's great that you solved your issue, but could you [edit] and expand upon your answer a little? Are you referring to the z-axis stepper driver? If so, turning in which direction?